# Why do clang and gcc produce this sub-optimal output (copying a struct) for passing a pointer to a by-value struct arg?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, clang, compiler-optimization

I have a C program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct sa {
    char buffer[24];
};

void proceed(const struct sa *data);

static inline void func(struct sa sa) {
    proceed(&sa);
}

void test(struct sa sa) {
    func(sa);
}
```

It seems that in the optimal assembly output of `test` function, the address of the `sa` argument of it can be directly passed to `proceed` function, since the `proceed` function is guaranteed not to change `data`. However, the compiler (both x86-64 clang 14.0 and gcc 12.1, -O3 optimization level) emits assembly like:

```
test:                                   # @test
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 48]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        movaps  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsp + 32]
        movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp], xmm0
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    proceed
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

Note that in the output, the whole `sa` struct is copied from [rsp + 32] to [rsp]. Why does the compiler not eliminate such copy?

Comment: There's no guarantee that `proceed` does not change the copy, the const qualifier does not imply that (it could cast its argument to a non-const-qualified pointer), but in principle the compiler still could perform the optimization you're asking about; it's a bit difficult because the copy needs a unique address, while the original doesn't.

Comment: This is a missed optimization. Probably the compiler is getting confused by the stack alignment requirements for arguments passed through the stack. If you change `struct sa` to `int`. GCC eliminates the copy for x86_64 platforms where `int`s are passed through registers [[1](https://godbolt.org/z/xPxPafnWq)]. However with `-m32`, GCC fails to eliminate the copy even with `int` [[2](https://godbolt.org/z/dno4dveox)] Also, note that passing structs by value is uncommon in C projects, perhaps because compilers were known to produce bad code in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is pretty clearly a missed optimization bug since it only happens with that extra level of inlining `func()`**.

You can report bugs on https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc  (GCC bug reports prefer AT&T syntax, so select that in your Godbolt link; it's generally good to include a Godbolt link in a GCC bug report along with the actual code and asm, so it's quick for future readers to check if it's been fixed, or play around with it.)

For GCC, use the keyword `missed-optimization`.

---

> since the proceed function is guaranteed not to change `data`

No, it's legal to cast away `const` because the original pointed-to object is not `const`.  But it still doesn't need to copy; your function owns its stack arg space, and can let other functions modify the only copy if it wants.  (Most calling conventions work this way, including all System V conventions such as x86-64 SysV which is in use here. Also I think Windows x64, where args larger than 8 bytes are passed by non-constant(?) reference to space reserved by the caller, with a pointer in a register, or on the stack if there are 4 or more args before it.)

The caller of `test` *can't* assume it's unmodified, so another call with the same arg would need to re-copy the struct after this returned.  Even `foo(const struct sa);` would work this way; there's no way to declare / promise that a function doesn't reuse its stack arg space for scratch space or args to tail-calls.

---

**[This test-case on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXAGx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQAJlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMQSACykAA6oCoS2DM5uHt7xickCAUGhLBFRXLGWmNYpQgRMxARp7p4%2BZRUCVTUEeSHhkTEW1bX1GU39HYFdhT0lAJQWqK7EyOwcCgTErtYA1ApMGwCkAOwAQrsaAIIbFxvICDUbYa5UVJG7AKyHXtGvACK7AMzHZwOP3%2BJ1OoIAbqg8OgNnFiKhFph0BA0AwVltVusCFsdgAqdBMapTP4AsFnUyE1Z4e4ETCmKAMKEMWhjKbEs4rQl4ZAbSHQjZUVwMZAQFZrTbbHFTPZHUGXWHwxHI3ZeSTbYkgwH7H6As58mG0lbGMVY0WYiU7dUy0nywXC0VMDWkoGg0EAejdOLYGyYCg2jIYgRZQQFQuQ7rd%2Bo2hoIxvNsfwxHKBDN4uxkqtB1JHvlcIRmCREBVasdJIjLt1YK8vzwVA2GghUJheaVxkCBDiKIE6PbG3xhNLmtOHopBCpNLpxgZTODmDZoM5Nh5QbGvKboeFbcEEF7mdlZ1zioL6C3HaLqvVZa1OtOUZj7Z3gil1rllztyFPDqdru1jf598EYxE2TR900dF8D0uFtj1PTti0vIcKyrX4HFrDgZloTgXl4TwOC0UhUE4RwtjmBZMD2aseFIAhNHQmYAGsQF%2BSQADoAE5fg0LhVQ0DQvC8NiNDY6RMI4aIcNogjOF4BQQA0ajaJmOBYCQNAWDiOhInISg1I0%2BgomQYAFGYOIFAQVACD4OhaWIWSIDCSSwkCGoAE9OCotS2EEAB5Zk3Lw3gsBYQxgHEALSGAipwUwWTwswVRylcWl3N4dtMFEqiWTCYhXOcLBJKpFgUpmKgDCMgA1PBMAAd28uJGBSmRBBEMR2CkJr5CUNRJN0Lh9BCkBTGMcwstkyAZlQOIbG7TgAFpvN%2BDZZoAdTEWgluWyJ4WIGT0uTFJ7AYJwXAaPR/DGAoij0BIkmm1IToyPqbpyBhOkuyYLD2loGDaAYHs8Prmju37Rnybpij6dpBgByHaje8GJBmBRSMWPRVgLYr9CwiTwsIjhVAADkkWbJGiDZgGQHkIExBh6OlCBHFIDZcEIEgKN%2BPqNmcdTNOIdmuCmXgaICtlSAQTAmCwKIIAY7w2JY/ZmJeaINEkUnfn2F59g%2BLGxJx/C8ZkuSFJF0hlMQFBUB5/TtK7a2ekpgwjGMGn6Ks2gbLshzwqc5hiH8jyra8ghfNofz8KCkKwojvAkyimLJPixLku4VLBHSxqspy/28qWfDCsx0qmAqqravq3CqP4ZrRHEdqq86lR1HC3QfCdkwzH0akxplgippSWL5sWla1o2raSF2qw7sO470hh86wYmCHnru6HruyO74cXvQgcqEZV8Br7gZGTersBvf/u34%2BLoRgXZnmVG%2BvRpYeAw7HSFwg3OEJ4nSauNuNmpmsWm9NGbM3wEQPmKoOZM25npSI7MvCCxNloUWjFfi/BYugrB2CcG63Eu/SShsLDG2Fig1%2BHAvD614EQ0hdFSDRVsgdaIQA)** demonstrates that it's a missed optimization: `test` will tailcall with just `jmp func` if it's `noinline`, not copying any args there.  And that non-inline definition of `func` won't copy either, just the expected RSP alignment then `lea  rdi, [rsp+16]` / `call  proceed` to pass a pointer to its stack arg.

**So adding `__attribute__((noinline))` to your `func` will result in your `test` calling `proceed` without copying the arg**, with just an extra `jmp` in the path of execution.  If that's legal, it would also be legal to do that when inlining `func`.

```
struct sa {
    char buffer[24];
};
void proceed(const struct sa *data);

__attribute__((noinline))
static void func(struct sa sa) {
    proceed(&sa);
}

void test_struct(struct sa sa) {
    func(sa);
}
// same as non-inline func()
// void test_struct_direct(struct sa sa) { proceed(&sa); }
```

```
# clang (trunk) -O3
# GCC is equivalent but uses sub/add instead of dummy push/pop
test_struct:
        jmp     func                            # TAILCALL
func:
        pushq   %rax                  # re-align the stack by 16
        leaq    16(%rsp), %rdi
        callq   proceed
        popq    %rax                  # clean up the stack
        retq
```

Feel free to shortlink that exact Godbolt link in your bug report, or with something commented or uncommented; it uses nightly builds of GCC and clang so devs will know it's not already fixed.  Also feel free to link this Stack Overflow Q&A, but your bug report should be self-contained and point out that the optimization is legal, and that uncommenting `__attribute__((noinline))` makes the difference.

(So probably for a bug report, you'd want `noinline` commented out, and uncomment the `test_struct_direct` version that manually inlines `func`.)